# Automatically highlight UITabBar Button

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm using this method http://redartisan.com/2010/6/27/uisegmented-control-view-switching-revisited to create a custom UITabBar and loading a particular view when a certain TabBarItem is clicked.

The problem is that initially the first view is loaded, but the first tab bar item is not highlighted.  Is there a way to force the highlight?  I'm not using the tabbarcontroller so I can't use its methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you make an instance variable: `UITabBar *tabBar;`
a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;
```

and connect this property to the UITabBar in Interface Builder, you can use:

```
for(UITabBarItem *tab in tabBar.items) {
    if ([tab.title isEqualToString: @"My Tab Title"]) {
        tabBar.selectedItem = tab;
        }
    }
```

This works if all tabs have a unique title, which is normally the case.